# QGraphicsView / QGraphicsScene Timer Event not working

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

I'm trying to implement a basic qtimer in a qgraphicsview but can't seem to get it working.

Here's my main.cpp code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {


    QApplication app(argc, argv);//should stay on the stack

    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();//this is the scene -- the canvas that holds everything!

    // a view just adds stuff to the scene in that view port

    QGraphicsView * view = new Game(scene);//create a new view

    return app.exec();
}
```

And here is the view header ... note the qtimer and advance function

```
class View: public QGraphicsView {//inherits qwidget -- so we can make it full screen there

    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        View(QGraphicsScene * _scene);//this is responsible for setting up the screen and instantiating several elements
        ~View();

    protected://variables
        QGraphicsScene * scene;
        QTimer * timer;


    protected://functions

        int const int_height();//converts qreal to an int
        int const int_width();

        qreal const height();// 
        qreal const width();//this is the actual qreal floating point number 

        virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event) {};
        void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * event) {cout << "HELLO << ads" << endl;};
        virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event) {};
        virtual void update() = 0;


        void advance() { cout << "HELLO WORLD" << endl;}        
    private:
        qreal _height;
        qreal _width;

};
```

And finally, my view implementation constructor:

```
View::View(QGraphicsScene * _scene) : QGraphicsView(_scene) {


    scene = _scene;//set the scene which is the parent over this 


    this->showMaximized();

    QRectF geometry = this->contentsRect();

    _height = geometry.height();
    _width = geometry.width();

    this->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    this->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, this->int_width(), this->int_height());
    // this->centerOn(qreal(0), qreal(0));

    this->setGeometry(0, 0, _width, _height);
    this->setFixedSize(_width, _height);


    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), scene, SLOT(advance()));
    timer->start(1000);
    timer->setInterval(100);



}
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen?  `QGraphicsScene::advance()` just tells all the items in it to 'advance()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your advance() function as a slot in the header file. Otherwise Qt does not know that this particular function is a slot:

```
protected slots:
    void advance() { cout << "HELLO WORLD" << endl; }
```

Then, you are connecting the timeout signal to the advance() slot in the scene - but you declared it in your view. As you are currently in the view, you can use the `this` pointer to connect the signal to your view. Change your connect like this:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(advance())); 
//                                ^^^^
```

[Edit] As a side node: You are creating a QGraphicsView subclass of type `Game`, but you showed the source code of `View`. This might be irrelevant if `Game` inherits from `View` though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and yes Game inherits from view, but I thought it would be easier to show just the view piece online :)